# I am getting error "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "httpclientconf' is already in use"

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, reactor-netty

I am running 2 Java cron jobs(only 1 application but called twice with 2 different job names) at the same time on a Kubernetes pod. Both jobs have http calls to other services.
For example:
java -Djob=jobX -jar application.jar
java -Djob=jobY -jar application.jar

One of the job succeeds but the other fails with below error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at reactor.netty.http.client.Httpclient.lambda$request$12(HttpClient.java:1042)
-[reactor-netty-0.9.20.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.20.RELEASEl
at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientBootstrap.configure(TcpClientBootstrap.java:39)
~[reactor-netty-0.9.20.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.20.RELEASE1
at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientBootstrap.configure(TcpClientBootstrap.java:39)
-(reactor-netty-0.9.20.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.20.RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientBootstrap.configure(IcpClientBootstrap.java:39)
-(reactor-netty-0.9.20.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.20.RELEASE]
reactor.netty.tcp.IcpClient.connect(TcpClient.java:212)-(reactor-netty-0.9.20.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.20.RELEASE]
at
reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientFinalizer.connect(HttpClientrinalizer.java:80)-(reactor-netty-0.9.20.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.20-RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientFinalizer.responseconnection(HttpclientFinalizer.java:97)~(reactor-netty-0.9.20.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpconnector.connect(ReactorClientHttpconnector.java:112)-[spring-web-
5.2.15.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.15.RELEASEl
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:104)
5.2.15.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.15.RELEASE]
-Ispring-webflux-
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUrispec.lambda$exchange$0(DefaultwebClient.java:338)-[spring-wel
5.2.15.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.15.RELEASE]
57
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)~(reactor-core-3.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.17.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe (Mono.java:4252) -(reactor-core-3.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.17.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono. java:1684) -[reactor-core-3.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.17.RELEASE]
at 
-- className and method
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:)
(spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:)(spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319)(spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1247)(spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1236)(spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.12.RELEASE]
at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method) -Ina:1.8.0_331]
at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)~(na:1.8.0_3311
at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java: 43) -(na:l.8.0_3311
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498) -Ina:1.8.0_331]
at
org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodrunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)(app.jar:0.0.56]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:108) (app.jar:0.0.56]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:58) (app.jar:0.0.56]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)(app.jar:0.0.56]
Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
"httpclientconf' is already in use
at
io.netty.util.constantPool.createOrThrow(ConstantPool.java:108)-[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.util.ConstantPool.newInstance(ConstantPool.java:90)-[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.util.AttributeKey.newInstance(AttributeKey.java:55)-(netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientconfiguration.<clinit>(HttpClientConfiguration.java:51)
-[reactor-netty-0.9.20.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.20.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, something is wrong with your deployment,

You could try to kill the existing usage on the port or change the ports test and try.

here is a tutorial to achieve it like
`` sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:YOUR_PORT ``